# How do I display sAMAccountName or alias of the LDAP contacts in Thunderbird?

Tags: ldap, thunderbird

`sAMAccountName` attribute is Active Directory unique username identifier, sometimes also present in the `alias` attribute.

The problem is the Thunderbird (11.0.1) does not show any of these LDAP fields in the interface.

How can I make it display these fields, as I found them essential for identifying users in systems where the email address does not contain your username.

Why is this question on StackOverflow: because the solution would require some coding, as I wasn't able to find anything already implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a way of implementing this without real coding:

Go to Edit > Preferences > Advanced > General > Config Editor:

`ldap_2.servers.default.attrmap.NickName = sAMAccountName`

Now you'll see the domain login (username) as nickname.

If only someone would know how to make Thunderbird lookup LDAP when you click on incoming emails.